# difference between cursor and select in a loop

Tags: plsql

I have been having this question for while now

we can Implement a cursor for Example

```
    SET serveroutput ON;
    DECLARE
      CURSOR test_cursor
      IS
        SELECT * FROM employees;
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN test_cursor
      LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.employee_id||' '||i.First_name);
      END LOOP;
    END;
```

Also  we can implement the same in below way

```
    SET serveroutput ON;
    BEGIN
      FOR rec IN
      (SELECT * FROM employees
      )
      LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.employee_id ||' ' ||rec.First_name);
      END LOOP;
    END;
```

Why do we need a cursor here then? Please could you let me know the differences and its advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: Check this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27045/why-use-explicit-cursors-instead-of-regular-loops

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, you actually use cursors.
The first one is declared and named (explicit).
The second one is anonymous (implicit).

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/01_oview.htm#740.

I usually use explicit cursors for better code readability and in cases, when I want to reuse the cursor, I can fetch the data from result cache or fetch the data into variable and iterate through an array.

Also, as far as I know, execution plan is not generated as often as while using the implicit cursor (the DB searches for the query in SGA by query's hash and can find already stored execution plan, thus skips the execution plan generation).

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_sqlproc.htm#TGSQL175

Answer (score 0):

So firstly, these are both known as cursor FOR LOOPs.

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1143

One usability difference between the two forms is that the second form places the SQL that is executing directly before the code in which the result set is used. This can make it easier to understand the code.

One useful syntax difference is that in the first form you can pass parameters into the cursor to modify its behaviour (see above link for syntax). So if you use the same basic cursor definition multiple times, but with different parameters to pass in, then use the former.